# Akka actors and messages best practic

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying to understand the tradeoffs and best practices (if there are) between the following options:

**Messages**

1. Many messages classes (e.g. *MessageClassForActorA, MessageClassForActorB, MessageClassForActorC*....) where every class has only the spesific fields that the target actor needs.
2. The above option were all the MessagesClass extends a basic class where some of the duplicated fields are stored.
3. One message class (e.g. *MotherOfAllMessages*) that contians all the fields that every actor in the system may need. Every actor in its turn uses (get / set) only the relevant fields out of this message

**Actors**

1. Actor can get meny messages types and the business logic is split accordingly

`.match(POJOA.class, message -> {`

...

`.match(POJOB.class, message -> {`

...

`.match(POJOC.class, message -> {`
...

2. Actor recieves only one message type and do all the different business logic according to some ENUM / parameter within the message

`if (POJO.getPhase().equals("start"))`

`...`

`else ...`

What is the common practice to use?
What is better in turms of performance, code maintanability etc.

Comment: This question is a bit too open-ended / opinion-based for SO's format. I have still answered it, but please consider following these guidelines in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

A mixture of A, B and C has worked very well for me so far. You want your messages as specific as you can (so they are self-explanatory), but you still need some generality.

For example: suppose you are using your actors as a key-value store.

You can have some generic Get/Set/Delete messages

```
public class Get {String key;}
public class Set<T> {String key; T value;}
public class Delete {String key;}
```

The issue is your Set message. It's type parametric. Some serialization frameworks do not  make that easy on you.

So you can change it to specific sets:

```
public class SetA {String key; A value;}
public class SetB {String key; B value;}
```

And bam, the type parameter is gone.

But the 3rd option is something you still need! Akka serialization requires you to bind a serializer to a class (the top level one), and in most cases you want to use a single serializer for all your messages, so the way to go for that is an empty interace:

```
public interface Message {}
public class Get implements Message {String key;}
public class SetA implements Message {String key; A value;}
public class SetB implements Message {String key; B value;}
public class Delete implements Message {String key;}
```

And then in your config file:

```
akka.actor{
  serializers {
    mySerializer = xxx
  }
  serialization-bindings {
    Message = mySerializer
  }
}
```